# jQuery slider with responsive design

Tags: jquery, slider

I want my site to be responsive and so I have changed my image thats a sprite image in 3 differend sizes.

Now I have this code and it works if all my images have a width of 600px but now I want the

`left: '-=600px'` to change so it takes the slideWidth. But how do I do that?

```
$(function() {
    var slides = $('.slide');
    var numberSlides = slides.length;
    var slideWidth = $('.slide').width();
    var wrap = $('#slideWrap')

    wrap.width(numberSlides * slideWidth);

    function moveMent() {
        for(r=0; r<100; r++) {
            for(i=0; i<numberSlides-1; i++) {
                wrap
                    .delay(3000)
                    .fadeTo(500, 0)
                    .animate({  
                    /*THIS NEEDS TO BE CHANGED:*/            
                        left : '-=600px'
                    })
                    .fadeTo(500, 1) 
            }
            wrap.delay(3000).fadeTo(500, 0).animate({left : '0'}).fadeTo(500, 1);
        }
    };

    moveMent(); 

 });
```

Comment: The CSS value already gets changed, if you resize window the slideWidth automaticly changes. So I need it to get the new slideWidth value afther resizing the window

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `left` animate property to `-slideWidth`:

```
$(function() {
var slides = $('.slide');
var numberSlides = slides.length;
var slideWidth = $('.slide').width();
var wrap = $('#slideWrap')

wrap.width(numberSlides * slideWidth);

function moveMent() {
    for(r=0; r<100; r++) {
        for(i=0; i<numberSlides-1; i++) {
            wrap
                .delay(3000)
                .fadeTo(500, 0)
                .animate({  
                /*THIS NEEDS TO BE CHANGED:*/            
                    left : '-=600px'
                })
                .fadeTo(500, 1) 
        }
        wrap.delay(3000).fadeTo(500, 0).animate({left : '0'}).fadeTo(500, 1);
    }
};

moveMent(); 

});
```

Here's a [proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/R4kJp/).